# @UniqueEntity not enforcing multiple-field constraint

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

In a Symfony 4 application that I've been asked to work on I am attempting to enforce a uniqueness constraint on the name of my program (a course of instruction, not software) within a given company.  Despite the attempted constraint, the app happily lets me create a program with the same name as one that already exists in the given company.

I've found various contradictory examples of how to set up a composite constraint, and I've read through the many StackOverflow questions on this topic to no avail.

The relevant code for my entity, program.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Domain\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Domain\AdminBundle\Service\Helper\RouteListHelper;
use Domain\CoreBundle\Repository\ProgramRepository as ProgramRepo;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use JsonSerializable;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

 /**
  * Program
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Domain\CoreBundle\Repository\ProgramRepository")
  * @ORM\Table(name="programs")
  * @UniqueEntity(
  *      fields={"name","company"},
  *      errorPath = "name",
  *      message="A program by that name already exists for this company."
  *      )
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  */

class Program implements JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Program Name should not be empty")
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $company;

...
```

and my addProgramType.php:

```php
<?php

namespace Domain\AdminBundle\Form;

use Domain\CoreBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

/**
 * Class AddProgramType
 */
class AddProgramType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $params = array(
            'name' => array(
                'label' => 'Program name:',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'base-box'),
            ),
            'isEnabled' => array(
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'checked' => 'checked',
                ),
            ),
            'isRoiCalculating' => array(
                'label' => false,
            ),
            'duration' => array(
                'label' => 'Duration:',
                'class' => 'DomainCoreBundle:Duration',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->getDurationsQb($options['company']);
                },
                'choice_label' => 'uniqueName',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'base-box',
                ),
            ),
            'sessionTypes' => array(
                'class'         => 'DomainCoreBundle:SessionType',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($options) {
                    return $er->getAllSessionTypesQb($options['company']);
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Session Types:',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'multiselect-dropdown multiselect-dropdown-session-types',
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                ),
            ),
            'users' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'DomainCoreBundle:User',
                'choices' => $options['userRepo']->findByRoles(
                        array(UserRepository::ROLE_ADMIN,UserRepository::ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN),
                        $options['company'],
                        false),
                'choice_label' => 'getFullName',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Access to admins:',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'multiselect-dropdown multiselect-dropdown-users',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                ),
            ),
        );

        $builder
            ->add('name', null, $params['name'])
            ->add('isEnabled', CheckboxType::class, $params['isEnabled'])
            ->add('isRoiCalculating', CheckboxType::class, $params['isRoiCalculating'])
            ->add('duration', EntityType::class, $params['duration'])
            ->add('sessionTypes', EntityType::class, $params['sessionTypes'])
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, $params['users']);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Domain\CoreBundle\Entity\Program'));
        $resolver->setRequired(array('company', 'userRepo'));
    }

    /**
     * Return form name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'add_program';
    }
}
```

While the application enforces the NotBlank constraint on the name correctly, it doesn't enforce the uniqueness of name + company.

Any suggestions?

[UPDATE] Looks like I set company after the isValid() call, thanks BoShurik for the catch.  Here's the relevant controller code showing my mistake:

```php
/**
     * Add new program
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function addNewAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(AddProgramType::class, null, array('company'=>$this->getCurrentCompany(),
                                'userRepo' =>$this->em->getRepository('DomainCoreBundle:User')));

        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $company = $this->getCurrentCompany();
                $program = $form->getData();
                $program->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime());
                $program->setCompany($company);
...
```

Comment: Can you share the controller (usage of this form)? Looks like you set company after `isValid()` check

Comment: You are indeed correct BoShurik, thanks for the catch! I've updated my original post to show the relevant piece of the controller. If you post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the correct response.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the same check at database level you should use the @UniqueConstraint annotation in the Table() declaration and give a name to the new index. 
Something like:

````
 /**
  * Program
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Domain\CoreBundle\Repository\ProgramRepository")
  * @ORM\Table(name="programs", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="IDX_PROGRAM_COMPANY", columns={"name", "company_id"})})
  * @UniqueEntity(
  *      fields={"name","company"},
  *      errorPath = "name",
  *      message="A program by that name already exists for this company."
  *      )
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  */

class Program implements JsonSerializable

```
````

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; I had already tried that approach and it still failed.  BoShurik correctly identified that I called isValid() before setting company.

Answer (score 1):

As a company field is not manager by your form, you need to set its value before form validation:

```php
public function addNewAction(Request $request)
{
    $program = new Program();
    $program->setCompany($this->getCurrentCompany());

    $form = $this->createForm(AddProgramType::class, $program, array('company' => $this->getCurrentCompany(),
        'userRepo' => $this->em->getRepository('DomainCoreBundle:User')));

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $program = $form->getData();
            $program->setCreatedDate(new \DateTime());
        }
    }
}
```